# How to compute the formula of discriminant of generic Weierstrass equation of elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, discriminant

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a field $k$ given by Weierstrass equation

$$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6\ .$$

Every standard book of elliptic curve includes the formula for discriminant $\Delta$ as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta &=-b_2^2b_8 - 8 b_4^3 -27 b_6 ^2 + 9 b_2 b_4 b_6\ ,
\text{ where}\\[3mm]
b_2 &= a_1^2 + 4 a_2\\ 
b_4 &= 2a_4 + a_1 a_3\\ 
b_6 &= a_3^2 + 4 a_6 \\
b_8 &= a_1^2 a_6 + 4 a_2 a_6 - a_1 a_3 a_4 + a_2 a_3^2 - a_4^2.
\end{aligned}
$$

But I would like to find the derivation of these quantities which I could not find in any of these books. It will be very helpful if I can get the derivation or any hints or any reference which includes the derivation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by a derivation? These quantities are just defined by the formulas you've given. If you want some intuition, Silverman describes in section III.1 of *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* how, when the characteristic is not $2$, the $b_i$ arise from completing the square of the LHS of the original equation.

Comment: By derivation, I want to mean that from where and how we get those quantities. I agree with you that some intuitions are given in section III.1 of Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves where $char \neq2,3$. But the given quantities here do not depend on the characteristic of the field. I want to compute them without being restricted by the characteristic of the field and then I want to apply them to the special forms of the Weierstrass equation over different fields with $char=2$ or 3 to get the exact value of discriminant.

Comment: A "derivation" is the main word in the text, and it is very misleading in the given mathematical context. I suppose the question is "...how to get these formulas?". We also do not have a question, an explicit one. Instead we have a wish. Well, these formulas are *definitions*, and they work in all characteristics. An answer covering all characteristics is a lot of typing work. If only the characteristics two **and** three are needed, then please restrict to these needs. Please restate, so that we have a **question** with a clear framework, and a clear target.